# How to open new tab on button click in laravel orchid with post data

Tags: php, laravel, orchid

I wanted to open a preview for news in my laravel orchid panel on submitting a form through post. My problem is when users click on preview button the preview is opening on same page but when we press back btn for final submitting the form, the data gets disappeared. So now i m thinking to open the preview on new tab. Anyone can suggest me a better idea to implement will be highly appreciated, I just wanted to show preview but the data should be available on pressing back button which will show thw form page. Thanks in advance

This is my screen

```
` public function commandBar(): array
    {
        $buttons[] = Button::make(__('Save'))
                ->icon('check')
                ->method('save');

         $buttons[] = Button::make('Preview')->id('ddd')
                   ->icon('check')
                   ->method('preview');
                   
        return $buttons;
    }`
```

and my preview function

```
 `public function preview(NewsItem $new, Request $request)
    {
       

        $newData = $request->get('new');
      
       
       return redirect()->away(route('platform.news.preview', [
             'newData' => $newData, 
         ]))->with('_blank');  // _blank does not works
       
    }`
```

I tried to redirect with   ->with('_blank') but it doesnt worked

Comment: Opening something in a new tab is only something you can trigger from the browser-side. The PHP has no knowledge of, and no access to, the browser. In fact it can't even be sure that whatever is making a request to it is even a browser at all. When you issue a redirect from PHP, it simply sets a HTTP response header. It's up to the client code receiving that to decide what to do with it. In the case of a browser, it will navigate to the URL in the header value (other clients may not). There's nothing you can put in the header to tell it to open a new window/tab instead.